# Dropped and Recreated ArangoDB Databases Retain Collections

Tags: arangodb

A deployment script creates and configures databases, collections, etc. The script includes code to drop databases before beginning so testing them can proceed normally. After dropping the database and re-adding it:

```
var graphmodule = require("org/arangodb/general-graph");
var graphList = graphmodule._list();
var dbList = db._listDatabases();

for (var j = 0; j < dbList.length; j++) {
   if (dbList[j] == 'myapp')
       db._dropDatabase('myapp');
}

db._createDatabase('myapp');
db._useDatabase('myapp');

db._create('appcoll'); // Collection already exists error occurs here
```

The collections that had previously been added to mydb remain in mydb, but they are empty. This isn't exactly a problem for my particular use case since the collections are empty and I had planned to rebuild them anyway, but I'd prefer to have a clean slate for testing and this behavior seems odd.

I've tried closing the shell and restarting the database between the drop and the add, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Is there a way to cleanly remove and re-add a database?

Comment: did the reply answer your question? if yes, can you mark the answer accepted? if not, whats missing?

Comment: It was using the correct database. The script also checks for and drops a graph. This would seem redundant since the entire database is dropped but when I move that block to before the db._create('appcoll') line the issue is resolved. The appcoll collection is used in the graph. Is there a residual reference to a graph collection that persists after a database is dropped?

Comment: If you create a [named graph](https://docs.arangodb.com/Glossary/index.html#named-graphs) its managementdata is kept in the system collection `_graphs`. You should drop a graph [via the graph management functions](https://docs.arangodb.com/GeneralGraphs/Management.html#remove-a-graph). Another thing relating to graphs is the UI which uses browser storage to remember graph settings.

Comment: That makes sense and is consistent with behavior I'm seeing. If you respond as a solution I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArangoDB stores additional information for [managed graphs](https://docs.arangodb.com/Glossary/index.html#named-graphs);

Therefore when working with named graphs, you should use [the graph management functions](https://docs.arangodb.com/GeneralGraphs/Management.html#remove-a-graph) to delete graphs to make shure nothing remains in the system:

```
var graph_module = require("org/arangodb/general-graph");
graph_module._drop("social", true);
```

The current implementation of the graph viewer in the management interface stores your view preferences (like the the attribute that should become the label of a graph) in your browsers local storage, so thats out of the reach of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

The collections should be dropped when `db._dropDatabase()` is called.
However, if you run `db._dropDatabase('mydb');` directly followed by `db._createDatabase('mydb');` and then retrieve the list of collections via `db._collections()`, this will show the collections from the current database (which is likely the `_system` database if you were able to run the commands)?.

That means you are probably looking at the collections in the `_system` database all the time unless you change the database via `db._useDatabase(name);`. Does this explain it?

Comment: I added additional code from my script to show where I'm trying to switch databases. I do see your point though and there may be a more subtle issue. I'll take a closer look and update back here soon.